# How to build and send expo.dev react-native ios/android app to a friend

Tags: react-native, expo

I have an example expo eas react-native app, and trying to figure out how can I share it without publishing apps to a store.
(I have google and apple development accounts)

**eas.json**

```json
{
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 5.6.0"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "extends": "production",
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "developmentClient": false,
      "extends": "production",
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "production": {
      "developmentClient": false,
      "autoIncrement": true,
      "env": {
        "EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL": "https://example.com"
      }
    }
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
...
```

i use bun and have bun.lockb

**app.js has eas config:**

```json
{
  "extra": {
    "eas": {
      "projectId": "...."
    }
  },
....
```

I can build locally android app and remotely both android and ios, but everytime i run it just shows me expo interface asks to run development client(it works fine when I do)
the app has my custom icon. ios device is registered in eas

but I want to run my app without development client so friend of mine can play with the app without a dev server
Is it even possible with expo? or I need to distribute ios app only via TestFlight?

I tried developmentClient=true

```json
 "preview": {
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
```

it just show expo interface and ask for development server

when I do

```json
 "preview": {
      "developmentClient": false,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
```

my app just starts and closes and I don't even know where I can find debug logs
(I can start my app with npm run:android fine)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to make an application without the developmentClient. My `eas.json preview` looks like this:

```json
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
```

By using the following command

> eas build --profile preview --platform android

If your app crashes, you can install the newly build application on an emulator or on your own device and link with it through `adb`

First look for the devices

> adb devices

and then link with it and look for errors. This command will only show errors in real time.

> adb logcat "*:E"

For Google I both use the `internal testing` option since this is way handier than sending out .apk files to each person. And it updates automatically!

For IOS, i found no other way than using TestFlight.

Comment: What do you see when you build your app with `eas build --profile preview --platform android` and install apk?  expo or your app straight away?

what is `internal testing` ?

Comment: a link to expo.dev, which after a while, you can download and install. `Internal Testing` is a mode on Goole Developer Console where you can place your application to test it internally before fully launching it on the App Store. You can even choose your audience by inviting them by email.